# Singleton can't be dumped - cached_resource gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeresource, ruby-2.2, rails-4-2-1, cached-resource

Using [cached_resource](https://github.com/Ahsizara/cached_resource) gem for caching active resources.

**User model**

```
class User < ActiveResource::Base
  cached_resource

  class teachers < SimpleDelegator
    attr_accessor :teacher_id

    def initialize(attributes = {}, _persisted = true)
      @teacher_id = attributes['teacher_id']
      super(User.find(@teacher_id))
    end
  end
end
```

I am trying to cache user resources.

`/users/:user_id`

Whenever I am calling /users/:user_id endpoint it gives me error singleton can't be dumped at line `super(User.find(@teacher_id))`

Please suggest if any other gem can help me in caching activeresource calls.

Comment: Check this blog post http://bloggershetty.blogspot.in/2007/04/ruby-typeerror-singleton-cant-be-dumped.html could help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gem `activeresource-response` was causing that problem. It was making my class singleton. Because of that it was throughing singleton dump error.